# Ways to make easy gold in skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have heard of many different ways to make easy gold, hacks, glitches, and rare items. But is there a way where I *don't* have to glitch, sell one of a kind items, and etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer for the question linked by @Ender is very good, but also very boring. The thing I always did when I was a bit short on cash was fast travel between cities/villages, which would spawn a dragon every now and then (about a quarter of the times if I remember correctly). Then if you kill the dragon you can loot it and sell the spoils (or craft armor from them). I don't know if it is very fast compared to other methods (like alchemy), but it definitely is more fun as you get to actually play the game instead of standing at an alchemy lab all the time. Using this method also levels your combat skills fairly quickly and it gets you dragon souls.

Comment: Thanks enjoy this link to my Secret Language                       https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CCM_M4KNIWY&src_vid=a5Xcpi81a5k&feature=iv&annotation_id=annotation_721675